# PHP Find all substrings within a string that contain a period and end with a space

Tags: php, substring

How do I get the substrings below from the $qryString in php? I have a database of over 300 query strings. They are all formatted with the dot operator. I would like to feed in the strings to a function and get a list of the tables returned.

```
$qryString = "SELECT * FROM Database.dbo.table INNER JOIN Database.dbo.Anothertable WHERE... ";
```

//OUTPUT

Database.dbo.table

Database.dbo.Anothertable

Comment: sorry, am i to understand you have a database table of _queries_?

Comment: My web application procedurally generates report forms based on predefined inputs that are then used in a query that is stored in a table. The queries are parameterized and the form fields that are submitted are then used as the parameters for the query. The end user can run an adhoc report entering different criteria as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a space followed by word characters `[\w]+` followed by a `.` followed by word characters `[\w]+` and a space one or more times `+`:

```
preg_match_all('/ ([\w]+\.[\w]+)+ /', $qryString, $matches);
```

Look in `$matches[0]`.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that some of my queries have brackets - "SELECT * FROM [Database].[dbo].[table] INNER JOIN [Database][.dbo].[Anothertable] WHERE... "; How can I modify the preg_match to incorporate the brackets with the existing functionality.